# Unable to write or read using Firebase realtime database in Android app

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was just trying to write or read using Firebase realtime database in Android Studio, but it seems that I just can't. I have like an invisible wall that blocks me, since I don't get even any errors, so, I really don't have a clue about what could it be.

This is the code that I am using in Android Studio:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
```

As you can see, it is just the default writing code that Firebase suggests you to use the first time.

I am pretty sure that my rules in the database are correct, because they are pretty basic:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

I am also sure that I ave a reference called message since I have created it:

```
{
  "message": ""
}
```

I am also sure that I can connect to internet since I have this in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And last I am sure that I am on the right database, since I have already developed a login and signup authentication that works fine, it's just that it seems I am not able to write (or read) to realtime database and I can't really understand why. Please help me.

I was just trying to write from Android to Firebase realtime database and it seems that I am not able to do that but I don't understand why.

Comment: If you [attach a completion listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback) to the write operation and log what happens, does it succeed? Or does it fail?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.